# Label в качестве кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

```
import tkinter


win = tkinter.Tk()
img_photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='resources/playpause.png')

def func():
    print('test')

label = tkinter.Label(win, image=img_photo)
label.place(x=0, y=0)
label.bind('<Button-1>', lambda: func)

win.mainloop()
```

`bind` работает, но выдаёт ошибку:

> "TypeError: lambda() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

по-сути нужно сделать `Label` с изображением в качестве кнопки.

Comment: Обработчики событий должны принимать параметр event (описание события). Добавьте лямбде игнорируемый параметр: `label.bind('<Button-1>', lambda _: func)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или как вариант:

Привязать функцию к клавишам мыши: левая клавиша – '`<Button-1>`'

`label.bind('<Button-1>', func)` - выполняется функция `func` при нажатии на левую клавишу мыши.

Обратите внимание! В заглавии функции `func` после ее названия
в скобках стоит слово **`event`** (с англ. событие).

```
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()
img_photo = PhotoImage(file='ball.png')

def func(event):
    print(f'test: {event.x}; {event.y}')
    
label = Label(win, image=img_photo)
label.place(x=0, y=0)
label.bind('<Button-1>', func)

win.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]